# Get the row indexes where 1 appears for each column

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-3.7

I have a binary numpy array and the array contains one 1 in some columns or complete zeros i.e. row sum of the array is a binary vector like

```
A = array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to find the row indexes where 1 appears in each column. If there is no one in each column then no need to return any index.

In the above case, I want the result as

```
[3, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

numpy where results are not usable at it iterates row wise

Comment: Is `A` your input, or is it something derived from your input? I cannot get this from your description... Also, please show us approaches that you've already tried and what is wrong with them.

Comment: Yes, A is my input.  So far, I tried with np.where only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
rows, cols = np.where(A==1)
result = rows[np.argsort(cols)]
```

This gives `array([3, 2, 3, 0, 0])` as a result.
It will only work if your assumption of maximum one appearance of 1 in each column is met.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `where` on the transpose of A:

```
np.where(A.T)[1]
# array([3, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```